# __ob__: Observer instead of my array of objects ( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) NOT WORKING )

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I need to input files in alphabetical order, and when I pass the files from one array to another the order is mixing up.
Here is the method that takes the files:

```
updatePreviews() {
  if (this.plan.gallery == null || this.plan.gallery.length == 0) {
    this.plan.gallery = [];
  }

  if (this.files?.length == 0) {
    this.planImages = this.oldImages.filter((o) =>
      this.planImages.map((o) => o.name).includes(o.name)
    );
  }
  this.files.forEach((file) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    fileReader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      if (
        !this.planImages
          .map((g) => g.name)
          .includes(file.name)
      ) {
        this.planImages.push({
          name: file.name,
          type: this.viewTypes[0],
          url: fileReader.result,
          description: "",
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Now see what happens when I log **this.files
[The order is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSDnQ.png)** (Line 417)

But when I **log this.planImages** (Which I call from vue)
[**This is what happenes**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdAV5.png) They are wrapped into an observer and the order is different than the array of files.
This is the vue code where I call this.planImages to be displayed and it works fine

```html
<v-row v-for="(image, index) in this.planImages" :key="index">
      <v-text-field
        label="Name"
        class="ma-4"
        v-model="image.name"
        readonly
        full-width
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-combobox
        class="ma-4 mt-10"
        label="View Type"
        v-model="image.type"
        :items="viewTypes"
      ></v-combobox>
      <v-icon class="pt-4 pr-4" @click="deleteImage(index)"
        >mdi-delete</v-icon
      >
    </v-row>
```

Now... I think this is because the file's name has special characters like "()", but I can't apply any sort method because I can't access anything since the files are nested into the observer.

I've been dealing with this for a while now and here are some of the things I tried and the result:

The most common solution I saw is

```
 const testJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.planImages));
  console.log(testJSON);
```

This just gives me an empty array back

The only thing that seemed to work for me was:

```
this.planImages.__ob__ = new Object({});
```

**[Which gives me this back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx4rv.png)**
As you see it gives me back an array with the files (Still mixed up) but it prints this error:
*Uncaught TypeError: ob.observeArray is not a function*

I couldn't figure out a way out of this, if someone could please tell me why I can't get to the root of all this I would really appreciate it

Comment: Please read [ask], which notes "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** -- copy or type the text into the question."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__ob__` is an internal property used by Vue's reactivity system, and  should not be manually modified.

The element order of `this.planImages` differs because its array elements are pushed upon the `FileReader`'s `load` event, which occurs at different times based on the file sizes. The order seen in `this.planImages` is likely smallest file to largest file.

To preserve the array order, insert the loaded files into the new array at the original index:

```js
updatePreviews() {
  ⋮
  this.planImages = [];       
  this.files.forEach((file, index) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    fileReader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      ⋮                 
      this.planImages[index] = {
        name: file.name,
        type: this.viewTypes[0],
        url: fileReader.result,
        description: "",
      }
    });
  });
}
```